# Create new instance with old instance which we do not know the constructor parameter

Tags: python

I have a new class called DataSheet which is inherit from Pandas.

```py
class DataSheet(DataFrame):
    def __init__(self, name=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.name = name
```

The initial dataFrame comes from `pd.read_excel()`.
Is it possible construct new DataSheet instance with pandas directly?

Currently, my solution is

```py
DataSheet(
    name=k,
    data=v.to_dict(),
    index=v.index,
    columns=v.columns,
)
```

There is a same question about `FT4222`[doc](https://msrelectronics.gitlab.io/python-ft4222/api.html#ft4222).

I want to wrtie a new class (eg. `my_FT4222`) inherent `FT4222` and I can get the instance by `ft4222.openByDescription`.

Can I use the instance comes from `ft4222.openByDescription` to create `my_FT4222`?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, you want to create an instance of DataSheet using pandas which might be something like `pd.DataSheet()`, is that right ?

Comment: Hold up, why are you using inheritance in the first place? Composition would be easier, no? Does your real class add any functionality besides a name? On that note, `self.name` isn't guaranteed to be a plain attribute; it could be a column of the df. Using composition would entirely avoid having to deal with that. And of course, then you wouldn't have to instantiate a new object.

Comment: @rr_goyal No, the data structure only for private and not be included pd.

Comment: @wjandrea The field is designed to record datasheet name and other is same as DataFrame so inherit is better than composition.

Comment: @TaiJuWu Oh! If all you want to do is add metadata to a df, you can just put it in [`df.attrs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.attrs.html)!

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about how the object was constructed, just grab the data you need in order to recreate it. For a Pandas dataframe, that means the index, columns, and data (as you're doing), plus dtype. The easiest way is to just pass the dataframe itself:

```
DataSheet(data=df, name='some_name')
```

Although, this doesn't copy `df.flags`. Also note that it doesn't copy `df.attrs`, but that's by design.

By the way, `self.name` [could be a column of the dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/dsintro.html#dataframe-column-attribute-access-and-ipython-completion), so you'd need to go the long way to set it as a plain attribute, I believe like this:

```
self.__dict__['name'] = name
```